# How do i setup a project with a "complicated" groovy OAUTH application with redirect

Tags: grails, groovy, oauth-2.0, parameter-passing

Im trying to setup a groovy app where I'm trying to integrate a third party service. They have an OAUTH process where the user clicks on a button and is redirected to their site to login and "grant" my app access to their service (somewhat like facebook). BUT - They are then redirected back to the app with a user "code" in the url as a parameter, which is then used to get an OAUTH token on the user's behalf through a different endpoint. I'm having an issue getting the "code" on the redirect. can anyone help?

`wwww.someurl.com?code=2l314jhlk13...2134lkj23h4==`

how can groovy listen for the redirect? I don't know where to go from here and the service i am using dosn't have any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what service would you like to integrate.
In some of them you can skip redirect. Some of them provides SDK with ready to use solutions.

If nothing - you need to http server.

If you app is a plain groovy without any web frameworks, probably the simplest solution is to use JDK built in http server.

Example - http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/the-jdk-built-in-web-server-with-apache-groovy